# Dynamic initialization of enum class inside template struct

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, struct, enums, clang

I was compiling following test code with clang :

```
template<typename T> struct S1
{
   struct S2{
       enum class E1;
       enum class E2: T;
       enum class E3: short;
    };

    typename S2::E1 b1;
    typename S2::E2 b2;
    typename S2::E3 b3;

    enum class S1::S2::E1 {e11,e12};
    enum class S1::S2::E2 : T {e21,e22};
    enum class S1::S2::E3 : short {e31,e32};
};

template struct S1<int>;
```

I got error : template specialization or definition requires a template parameter list corresponding to the nested type 'S1< T >'. My guess is since struct S1 is being defined while adding member in

```
enum class S1::S2::E1 {e11,e12} 
enum class S1::S2::E2 : T {e21,e22};
enum class S1::S2::E3 : short {e31,e32};
```

the compiler does not know what is T since S1 is not instantiated yet and hence T cannot be resolved. The compiler thus does not know the size for the enum members and hence throws error. Is this correct? Is it specified in standards?

Note : gcc does not throw any such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply not allowed to define an `enum` like that. Paragraph 7.2/4 in n3337 states:

> If the *enum-key* is followed by a *nested-name-speciﬁer*, the *enum-speciﬁer* shall refer to an enumeration that
>   was previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the *nested-name-speciﬁer* refers (i.e.,
>   neither inherited nor introduced by a *using-declaration*), and **the *enum-speciﬁer* shall appear in a namespace
>   enclosing the previous declaration.**

Granted, the error message is not exactly stellar. Your example can be vastly simplified to this:

```
template<typename T> struct S1
{
   struct S2 {
       enum class E;
   };

   enum class S2::E {};
};
```

which will produce the same error message.

Valid options are:

```
// definition in the scope that the declaration appears in
template<typename T> struct S1
{
   struct S2 {
       enum class E;
       enum class E {};
   };
};
```

or

```
// definition in the enclosing namespace scope
template<typename T> struct S1
{
   struct S2 {
       enum class E;
   };
};

template<typename T>
enum class S1<T>::S2::E {};
```

The same rule applies also for nested classes (see 9.7/3). If you try this

```
template<typename T>
struct S1
{
   struct S2 {
       struct S3;
   };

   struct S2::S3 {};
};
```

then GCC, too, produces a (similarly unhelpful) error. That it doesn't do the same with enums appears to be a bug.

And your own explanation you brought up for the error is incorrect. In the definition of a template the compiler doesn't need to (and obviously can't) know what `T` is. It only needs it when it instantiates the template. How else would something like `template<typename T> struct X { T obj; };` work?